# ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3.10" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

Tags: python, docker, heroku

I am trying to push my API on Heroku.

Here is my Docker file

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN apt-get update -y 
RUN apt-get install nano unzip
RUN apt-get install -y python3.10
RUN apt install curl -y

RUN curl -fsSL https://get.deta.dev/cli.sh | sh

COPY requirements.txt /dependencies/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /dependencies/requirements.txt

COPY . /home/app

CMD gunicorn app:app  --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

when pushing on heroku my app I get the error

```
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   5 |     RUN apt-get update -y 
   6 |     RUN apt-get install nano unzip
   7 | >>> RUN apt-get install -y python3.10
   8 |     RUN apt install curl -y
   9 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3.10" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/shc8h2vxc4zp5now7sazsi4y1
 ▸    Error: docker build exited with Error: 1
```

It seems that the problem is with the install of python3.10 but what to do precisely ?

the command i made is : heroku container:push web -a getaround-api-jl2024

Thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: Does this build _locally?_ I suspect not, in which case it has nothing to do with Heroku. Before trying to deploy, make sure it's working on your development machine.